# Overload resolution for pointer to function

Tags: c++, function

When the function is called it's clear how name-lookup and overload resolution is performed. But what happens when the funtion is not being called? E.g.

```
#include <iostream>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;

void foo(int){ cout << "foo(int)" << endl; }
void foo(int, int){ cout << "foo(int, int)" << endl; }

void (*baz)(int, int);


int main()
{ 
    baz = foo; //1
    baz(1, 1); 
}
```

**[DEMO](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f3bbe96c6a33dfaa)**

In that case we have two functions with the name `foo` and formally, the unqualified name lookup finds both them. The clause 13 of the Standard doesn't cover that case because it's concerned only in the function call context `N3797:13.3/2 [over.match]`:

> Overload resolution *selects the function to call* in seven distinct
>   contexts within the language:

Comment: `foo` is implicitly being converted to `void (*)(int, int)` so there is no overload resolution happening here -- *you* are implicitly selecting a specific overload when you assign to a function pointer of a particular type.

Comment: @cdhowie not quite clear. The name lookup finds both two functions and then tries to implcitly covert each function to `void (*)(int, int)`, right?

Comment: A variable cannot have two values - so the compiler selects the one with the same type,. In this case it is `foo(int,int)` as given when you run your demo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The behavior in this case is governed by this verbiage in the C++11 standard (there is a similar section in N3797):

> A use of an overloaded function name without arguments is resolved in certain contexts to a function, a pointer to function or a pointer to member function for a specific function from the overload set. ... **The function selected
>   is the one whose type is identical to the function type of the target type required in the context.**  -- ISO/IEC 14882:2011(E) §13.4 [over.over] (emphasis mine)

The standard overload resolution rules aren't used here because you are assigning to a function pointer type, so the compiler will simply select the function overload that exactly matches the type of the function pointer.